# SQL parameters in trace don't match assigned values in c#

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I have an app doing searches with multiple fields for different criteria.

[Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Em2.png)

My data models seem to be updating accordingly when I debug, but what I pass as SQL parameters isn't correct I think. A SQL trace showed me this is whats being sent to the DB.

`exec nu_sp_Codetable_GetWSub @address=N'1234 r%', @wo=N'%', @sub=N'%', @daysback=1096, @marketareaid=99, @po=N'%', @plan=N'%', @super=N'%', @builder=N'%'`

My question has to do with those "N" in front of my actual parameter values (we are using modulus for default because reasons). I don't know where it came from, if it came from my code. Here is the code that submits this search to the DB.

`UpdateMainGrid(String.Concat(Address, "%"), "%", "%", SelectedDaysBack,     SelectedMarketAreaItem.marketareaid, "%", "%", "%", "%")`

I ran this as the simplest form of the search and you can see where the code (for this particular search) has those default modulus hard coded for each parameter. In this example, only the Address variable is actually a set value.

Couple notes, the update method shown above passes the literal strings into the classes we use to connect to SQL, which is why I haven't provided the code for that. Debugging shows that the data doesn't change during these steps, it's just different in the SQL trace. Also, the other queries I've looked up in the trace DO NOT include the 'N'. I don't know what difference that makes, if any.

Comment: The 'N` just means the value is treated as NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: Thank you. That's quite simple an answer. I fail at google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N is used in SQL to denote a unicode string.

It stands for National language character set.

Much like you can do this in C#:

`decimal d = 0.3m;`

The extra m on the end doesn't change the actual value, it is just a more explicit representation.

Comment: So it means absolutely nothing to the SQL execute statement? I may be oversimplifying, but varchar and nvarchar, while inherently different, wouldn't have any different behavior in this case?  I pushed the execute from the trace manually and got the same lack of results. I just want to be sure before I start dissecting my SQL query to figure out why it didn't work.

Comment: It can make a difference, especially with indexes when you pass in a nvarchar but the column with a index is varchar, it will convert the column to nvarchar for the comparison and not use your index.

Comment: Am I wrong to only include the '%' as the parameter when testing, or do I need to put the 'N' as it is in the exec? Also, would it be proper to change the parameter data type in the script to nvarchar to match the notation on the exec? I don't really get the use or function of this 'N' notation and I want to be sure so while dissecting my SQL query, I'll figure out why it didn't work.

Comment: Because you are using a stored procedure nu_sp_Codetable_GetWSub it should not matter because it will just convert to the correct type when the procedure is called.

Answer (score 0):

By default, parameters are sent to sql as an nvarchar. This is done to allow it to accept the broadest possible values for a parameter, and handle the conversion to type based on the column in the server. That N simply defines the string as `Nvarchar`rather than `varchar`.